# Where is a good place to find Ruby Selenium tutorials and or documentation that explains what to use for what element?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Where is a good place to find Ruby Selenium tutorials and or documentation that explains what to use for what element?

Watir has a great place to find this type of information such as:

- [Watir Wiki](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Tutorial)
- [Watir Documentation](http://pettichord.com/watirtutorial/docs/watir_cheat_sheet/WTR/Cheat%20Sheet.html)

Anything that is similar to these websites for Selenium would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the horse's mouth:

1. http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html
2. http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html

Also... if you use the Firefox plugin you'll get inline documentation under a tab called "Reference" (a sister tab of the "Log" tab)

Comment: These are good resources but I need stuff more specific to Selenium 2 not just Selenium 1.